# Making Tumblr Landing Page

Tags: javascript, tumblr

On Tumblr, I am trying to make a landing page with, for example, an "Enter" button that brings the user to the home page. I found the following code that redirects the site to a /welcome page, which I placed in the index page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href == 'http://ihadcats.tumblr.com/') location.replace('http://ihadcats.tumblr.com/welcome');;
</script>
```

Of course, on the 'welcome' page, when you press `<a href="http://ihadcats.tumblr.com"` it just loops back to the welcome page.

I created a custom page '/home', to use instead of the index page. I placed the normal index code into a separate '/home' page, but the code doesn't render. It displays, for example "{Title}" instead of the actual title.

When the Index page is loaded, Tumblr bakes in a lot of its own scripts. When the '/home' page is loaded, none of Tumblr's scripts are loaded. Though the code in both pages is exactly the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to rewrite your last paragraph. I didnt understand what's going on there!

Comment: I was thinking about going with the full div approach, and didn't know if their was another way. Thanks for the advice, I think I'm going to go with that.

Comment: It might be easier to create some type of popup instead of a separate page.

Comment: @Radio is right. This is the best approach, I have built this on at least 3 tumblr accounts. Create a div inside the main template which is only shown on the index page, and then you can set a cookie so it only runs once per however many days you wish to set. You can also do it with a redirect, but I think that is messier.

Comment: not sure what happened to my comment. So odd. Anyhow, @inharby summed it up nicely too. If you get stuck, set a new question, glad to help.

Comment: @Radio don't know what happened to your comment either, but it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr variables and blocks don't render on custom pages, only in the main theme code. Basically it doesn't see them as special key words or anything it just sees them as a normal webpage would see them.

As for making a landing page you can tag every post you make with some arbitrary tag like 'x' and then make your index page a landing page and then wrap all your code in `{block:TagPage}` `{/block:TagPage}` so that the theme code only displays on tag pages (and you would code permalink pages like normal).

Alternatively you could do as suggested above and make a welcome 'popup' of sorts.