# Creating a Tumblr Landing Page Using Redirect Code

Tags: redirect, tumblr

there was a similar question to this one asked a while back - but for some reason the comment that contained specific instructions for the workaround was deleted.

I am attempting to create a landing page on a tumblr page using the redirect code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href == 'http://labellablog.com/') location.replace('http://labellablog.com/welcome');;
</script>
```

The issue that I'm experiencing is the same as the person who posted the question in the first place - by putting the redirect code in the index page, it creates a loop. i.e. In trying to click the link on the 'welcome page' in order to get to the home page containing blog posts, navigation etc., it simply re-directs to the 'welcome' page.

The solution that is mentioned (not in great detail) on another question states that you must set the cookies to expire in a certain amount of time. Unfortunately I'm a huge amateur when it comes to coding and am not entirely sure how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: for reference, here is the question that I mentioned:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222013/making-tumblr-landing-page

Comment: Hey, I think that was me. You don't actually have to set a cookie, you can just run a check so that the code only runs on the index page so http://labellablog.com but not http://labellablog.com/about for example. I will write an anwser using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Based on your question this is how I would resolve it (this is not using the cookie method at all, but I will come to that).

Make sure jquery is installed in your theme, alot of themes already have it, if not you can add it to the head of the document like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Lets look for the index page:

```
var primaryDir  = document.location.pathname.split("/")[1]; // get the first directory
if (!primaryDir){ // if the primary directory is empty (index page) lets redirect to another page
   window.location('/welcome');
}
```

You can use /welcome and that will work if you change the name/url of your site/tumblr.

So this method means this will always run (unless you disable javascript) for every client that connects to your site. This means effectively that the index page is never visible.

Now if you wanted a cookie method, this would mean that you would create the redirect on the first visit, then set the cookie and then after that the index page would be visible.

If that is what you want, let me know, but that involves quite a bit more code, slightly more complex solution.

**EDIT**

Another way to achieve this is to create a hidden div in the main template that only shows on the index page and is hidden on all other pages, this means you don't have to rely on a slightly slower redirect.

I only posted an answer to that issue the other day: [How can I make a Tumblr background image only for one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016379/how-can-i-make-a-tumblr-background-image-only-for-one-page/32052988#32052988)

**Method 2**

OK here is a method adopting cookies.

First I recommend downloading this [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

You will then need to link to that as a resource in your theme, so you need somewhere to host that file. I use dropbox, but tumblr also has a repository for linking to files (well it used to seems to have disappeared).

Now create an element that will sit over the main page:

```
<a href="#" id="entry">Enter</a>
```

You can style this to fill the whole page if required (modify to your needs):

```
#entry {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:#CCC;
  color:#FFF;
  // yadda yadda
}
```

Now we need some click event to create the cookie when we click on this huge anchor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var entry = $('#entry'); // lets cache the selector in a variable
   entry.on('click',function(){
      $.cookie('deadlyrhythm', '1', { path: '/', expires: 1}); // set a cookie with the name deadlyrhythm to the value of 1 on the entire site for 1 day. 
      $(this).hide();
      return false;
   });
});
```

Now we need a method to check if the cookie exists, so inside the same document ready function:

```
if ($.cookie('deadlyrhythm') != '1'){
   entry.hide();
}
```

This should mean that for 24 hours the cookie is set and the entry will not display if the same user revists the site, but it will after one day, of course you can set that value to anything you like.

As I mentioned this is slightly more complex to implement, but in the console of the browser you can check to see if a cookie exists and delete it manually (I use chrome for this) this is really useful for testing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try it and get back to you with any issues. I really appreciate the speedy help, you rule.

Comment: Okay, so I may just be a bit confused (forgive me if I am!). 

My intention is to keep my index page intact, but provide a 'welcome page' or 'splash page' as the initial introduction to the website. The splash page would have a click through link that would take the user to the index page (which normally serves as the 'home page' for this website/blog). 

I belive you provided an answer to the exact problem I'm facing on the other question (the one that I linked in the comments above). That user had gotten to the same step that I'm at.

Not sure if I'm just misunderstanding!

Comment: Yes, method 1: you would never see the index page. Method 2: you would see the index page after the splash/entry page. So I think the answer I linked to has what you need. But I can edit this question if that would help.

Comment: So it may be that the 'cookie method' is the only viable option to achieve what I'd like.

Comment: The person who originally asked this question seems to have worked out what I'm trying to for their tumblr page: http://ihadcats.tumblr.com/. 

That URL brings you to a splash page, through which you are redirected to their main page after clicking on animated text.

Again, I apologize if I'm misunderstanding you - you may have already provided the answer that I'm looking for. But I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Haha, yes I have done it on about 3 tumblr accounts myself. Let me see if I can post some code for you.

Comment: OK I have added a method with cookies.